# Read files from local computer and write to BigQuery or google storage using google dataflow

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

Is there a way to read csv files from a local computer and write it to big query or storage using google dataflow? If it exists, what runner should be used?

All the google dataflow examples either read from cloud and write to either to cloud storage or big query.

I use DirectPipelineRunner for reading from local computer and writing to local computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DirectPipelineRunner should work for this; you can use TextIO to read from your local input files and use BigQueryIO to write to BigQuery.